# Can any one suggest me wordpress plugin for slider that sync with navigation?

Tags: wordpress

Please see this image in which first link syncs with first slide 
[image: image1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the below mentioned plugins may help you :

=> https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-slider/examples/wordpress-slider-with-text-navigation-id33/

=> https://wordpress.org/plugins/kings-tab-slider/

Comment: Thank you, it's smiliar, but not exactly what i want :). I cant do css customizations.

Comment: Then I am afraid, you will not going to get the exact plugin. A bit customization you need to do for getting the look and feel as per your requirements ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://themeforest.net/item/reversal-horizontal-one-page-wordpress-theme/4974890

This should offer the functionality you are looking for. It works just like a onepage site but in horizontal orientation. You can even place html content instead of just pictures.

Comment: Thank you,But it's a theme. I need plugin